# HighCharts - неправильный задний фон для графика

Tags: html, css, highcharts

Дoбрый дeнь, буду краток.
Сейчас у меня вот так:
[image: График который сейчас у меня]

Мне нужно чтобы было вот так:
[image: График который мне нужен (сделано в фотошопе)]

Как это реализовать?
Пользуюсь HighCharts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данный вопрос следующим образом:
сделал для chart type area